# Angularjs and Cordova: can't use Angularjs factory

Tags: angularjs, cordova

My issue is, I'm creating, or at least trying to create, a angularjs factory but for some odd reason the factory object in Cordova.js is being referenced instead of the one in angular.min.js. For example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);



app.factory('', function(){
  //some stuff here.....
  
});
```

The statement "app.factory" is using the factory object from Cordova.js not angular.min.js. I have no idea what's going on at this point. The weird this is that is was working at one point, up until I tried to wrap the factory in a module. That seemed to screw things up. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Weird, hard to say what's going wrong. I use cordova and Angular with no problems. Maybe there's something wrong with you minified js? Is the app running in the browser without Cordova? Maybe use the https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console to see what the object 'app' is?

Comment: It partially runs, there is a eula page and a configure page and a login page. It pulls up the eula and config pages fine but nothing else works.

Comment: I kinda fixed it, kinda didn't. It seems to have been a issue VS 2012. I loaded the same exact project in VS 2013 and everything works like it should. Still don't have a clue as to what happened in VS 2012 that screwed everything up. Thanks for your help!